# How to know if it is empty or null on field by ID in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
<select id="division" multiple="multiple" title="Equipos seleccionados" style="width:143px;height:125px;overflow:scroll;">
<option value="1" title="Bundesliga">Bundesliga</option>
</select>
```

I'm doing this:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideFields");

function hideFields() {
    var control = findcontrol("equipo");
    control.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
}

function showFields() {
    var control = findcontrol("equipo");
    control.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "block";
}

function findcontrol(field) {
    var arr = document.getElementById(field);
    return arr;
}

document.getElementById("Division_AddButton").onclick = showFields();
```

but it does not happen to the `showFields ();`

What I want is that when there is nothing in `division` that does not show me the`team` and when there is something in `division` that the`team` appears

How do I do it in Javascript?
Javascript without any bookstore. The code is generated by Sharepoint

Visual what I want:

- At beginning

[image: Al cargar la pagina por defecto]

- When you add an element

[image: Al pasar una division a la parte derecha o seleccionarla]

Answer (score 0):

code looks fine. only comment i can make is that are you sure you are targeting the correct control and is it at the correct parent level. also as its from sharepoint its possible that its not been loaded in the DOM yet.

I dont know what version of sharepoint you are using? also does the hiding work in f12 developer running the js code within the browser to see if your targeting the correct control? if it is then load the control on dom load like below.

2010

```
function showHideCode(){
    var values = document.getElementById('division').val();;
    if (values != null || values.length > 0){
        showFields();
    }
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("showHideCode");
```

2013

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js','SP.ClientContext',showHideCode);

function showHideCode(){
    var values = document.getElementById('division').val();;
    if (values != null || values.length > 0){
        showFields();
    }
}
```

plain simple JS might work if the stuff you want to hide has no reliance on any of the sharepoint JS libraries to load

```
window.onload = function () { 

        var values = document.getElementById('division').val();;
        if (values != null || values.length > 0){
            showFields();
        }
}
```